# Background images/elements disappear when width/height is too large

Tags: html, css, animation

I have an interesting problem.

I was making the solar system for fun, which can be seen here:
http://jessemorgan.me/solar-system/

Everything is working fine until I add Saturn, or anything after Jupiter. When I do that, all background images disappear, however are still being loaded successfully. Then out of curiosity, I added Neptune as well and Saturn's border then wasn't visible.

After debugging, I found that if I lowered the width/height of Saturn's orbit significantly, everything became visible again. That, for obvious reasons isn't a solution though.

It's all pure css/html. I only added jquery for zooming and popups. So hopefully, the solution will be a rather easy one. I'm just not seeing it.

Saturn and Neptune have been commented out, but all of the code remains.

Does anyone know why it's going all wacky?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a note and I will expand later... have you run it without Javascript?  One of the parameters in your JS code could be funky, which would mess with how far you're "zoomed" in, when you really aren't--essentially cutting off parts of the solar system.

Comment: Haha! Yeah, that was it. I had tried it without the on-page js, but forgot I had an imported js library (easing.js), which I'm not even using. I removed it and it works fine. Thanks for the idea :)

Comment: I didn't have much time to mess with it last night. It appeared to work, but not quite. I uploaded a new version: http://jessemorgan.me/solar-system/   It's doing a weird flickering, but only if I remove the css scale. If it's set to `transform:scale(.4);` it just completely reverts to no images. Want me to create a jsfiddle to play with it?